# Broadcast Receive

Tags: android, service, android-broadcast

How to send a Broad Cast a message from an Android Device so that Another Android Device with in the vincity can receive the message and perform Appropriate Action and reply back to the sender. How to go about it? should I use Service or BroadCast Receiver ?

Answer (score -1):

the better option is to use android GCM you will have to implement push notification when it comes to send broadcast to particular device

see this

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: And if it is with vicinity of the closer area device i.e the devices in circle then there might be two ways with wich you can do it

bluetoothor ,SIP to just send the packete message and for this packets you will have to write custom broadcast receiver